# Need .NET code to execute only when in debug configuration

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, debugging

I have some code that access an API out on the web. One of the API's parameters allows me to let them know that I am testing.

I would like to only set this parameter in my code when I am testing. Currently, I just comment the code out when I do a release build.

Is there an automatic way of doing this based on the build configuration?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

## Solutions

You can use one of the following—

## 1:  `Conditional` attribute

The [`Conditional`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute) attribute indicates to compilers that a method call or attribute should be ignored unless a specified conditional compilation symbol is defined.

Code example:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
static void Method() { }
```

### 1b: `Conditional` attribute on local function (C# 9)

Since C# 9, you may use attribute on a local function.

Code example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    static void Method() { }

    Method();
}
```

## 2:  `#if` preprocessor directive

When the C# compiler encounters an [`#if`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) [preprocessor directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/), followed eventually by an #endif directive, it compiles the code between the directives only if the specified symbol is defined. Unlike C and C++, you cannot assign a numeric value to a symbol. The #if statement in C# is Boolean and only tests whether the symbol has been defined or not.

Code example:

```
#if DEBUG
    static int testCounter = 0;
#endif
```

## 3: `Debug.Write` methods

[`Debug.Write`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.write) (and [`Debug.WriteLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline)) writes information about the debug to the trace listeners in the [Listeners](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.listeners?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_Debug_Listeners) collection.

See also [`Debug.WriteIf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.writeif) and [`Debug.WriteLineIf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.writelineif).

Code example:

```
Debug.Write("Something to write in Output window.");
```

## Notes

Beware of using `#if` directive since it can produce unintended situations in non-Debug (e.g. Release) build. For example, see:

```
    string sth = null;
#if DEBUG
    sth = "oh, hi!";
#endif
    Console.WriteLine(sth);
```

In this case, non-Debug build will print a blank message. But, this potentially may raise `NullReferenceException` in a different case.

## Read more

- Eric Lippert. [What's the difference between conditional compilation and the conditional attribute?](http://ericlippert.com/2009/09/10/whats-the-difference-between-conditional-compilation-and-the-conditional-attribute/)
- C# Programmer's Reference: Conditional Methods Tutorial ([archive.org mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20110812082835/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288458(VS.71).aspx))
- Bill Wagner. [Effective C#: 50 Specific Ways to Improve Your C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321245660) (book), chapter: *Use Conditional Attributes Instead of #if*
- John Robbins. Assertions and Tracing in .NET ([archive.org mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20140418085730/msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301363.aspx))
- Sam Allen. *Dot Not Perls*:

  - [C# Conditional Attribute](https://www.dotnetperls.com/conditional)
  - [C# Debug.Write](https://www.dotnetperls.com/debug-write)

## See also

There is also a tool, [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx), which allow to capture debug information from external applications.

Comment: Those `Debug.WriteXXX` methods are also attributed with `[Conditional("DEBUG")]`.

Comment: Kudos for keeping this answer updated over the last 10 years :)

Answer (score 33):

yes, wrap the code in

```
#if DEBUG
// do debug only stuff 
#else
// do non DEBUG stuff
#endif
```

Google for ["C# compilation symbols"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691095(VS.71).aspx)

Visual Studio automatically defines `DEBUG` when you are in the debug configuration. You can define any symbols you want (look at your project's properties, the build tab). Beware that abusing preprocessor directives is a bad idea, it can lead to code that is very difficult to read/maintain.

Comment: Can you give an example of abuse?

Comment: I once worked on a project that had
`#if VERSION_1_1 // do version 1.1 specific stuff #elif VERSION_2_0 #if INCLUDE_FLASH // do flash specific stuff #elif HTML_RENDERER // HTML specific stuff #else /// etc #endif`

of course being a comment that doesn't format correctly, but you get the idea.

This was how they decided to maintain different releases. It was enough to make you want to go postal.

Comment: Ahh. Thanks for the advice. I'm not trying to do anything like that. I think branching with source control would probably be better in situations like that.

Answer (score 16):

I had this same problem and the solution I went with is using:

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    // Code here
}
```

This means that technically in production you can attach a debugger and get that piece of code to run.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to #if #endif directives, you can also use conditional attributes.  If you mark a method with the attribute

```
[Conditional("Debug")]
```

It will only be compiled and run when your application is built in debug mode.  As was noted in the comment below, these only work when the method has a void return type.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another post with a similar result : http://www.bigresource.com/Tracker/Track-vb-lwDKSoETwZ/

A better explanation can be seen at : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx

```
// preprocessor_if.cs
#define DEBUG
#define MYTEST
using System;
public class MyClass 
{
    static void Main() 
    {
#if (DEBUG && !MYTEST)
        Console.WriteLine("DEBUG is defined");
#elif (!DEBUG && MYTEST)
        Console.WriteLine("MYTEST is defined");
#elif (DEBUG && MYTEST)
        Console.WriteLine("DEBUG and MYTEST are defined");
#else
        Console.WriteLine("DEBUG and MYTEST are not defined");
#endif
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public int Method ()
{
#if DEBUG 
   // do something 
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following is safe to use:

```
var isDebug = false;
#if DEBUG
    isDebug = System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached;
#endif

if (isDebug) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in asp.net:

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
    //send email to developer;
else
    //send email to customer;
```

from Rick Strahl @ [Detecting-ASPNET-Debug-mode](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2007/Jan/19/Detecting-ASPNET-Debug-mode)