# #if (DEBUG) VS System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached

Tags: .net, visual-studio

What is different between using `#if (DEBUG)` and `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached` in visual studio? Are there cases of the `DEBUG` flag being set, but no debugger attached, or cases when a debugger could be attached when the `DEBUG` flag is not set?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`#if DEBUG` ensures the code is not included in the assembly at all in release builds. Also, code included by `#if DEBUG` runs all the time in a debug build - not just when running under a debugger.

`Debugger.IsAttached` means the code is included for both debug and release builds. And a debugger can be attached to release builds too.

It's common to use both together. `#if DEBUG` is usually used for things like logging, or to reduce exception handling in internal test builds. `Debugger.IsAttached` tends to just be used to decide whether to swallow exceptions or show them to a programmer - more of a programmer aid than anything else.

Answer (score 15):

`#if DEBUG` is a compile-time check, meaning the code it surrounds will only be included in the output assembly if the `DEBUG` preprocessor symbol is defined. `Debugger.IsAttached` is a runtime check, so the debugging code still gets included in the assembly, but only executes if a debugger is attached to the process.

Answer (score 6):

`#if (DEBUG)` is a preprocessor directive that allows you to conditionally compile code.

`System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached` provides a runtime value that indicates whether a debugger is attached to the process.

Comment: Can it detect if any debugger is attached? Or just managed debugger?

Comment: @JohnZaj [This](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/670193/csharp-detect-if-debugger-is-attached) says _only_ managed debuggers. `IsDebuggerPresent` detects _native_ debuggers. Whether it is applicable or not is another question.

Answer (score 4):

It has nothing in common.  You can debug the Release build.  And you can run the Debug build without a debugger, press Ctrl+F5.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional attributes are another related option to the ones listed above. Good answers related to this topic on this question.

[Need .NET code to execute only when in debug configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409598/need-net-code-to-execute-only-when-in-debug-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

```
        private void ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(IAppBuilder app)
        {
#if DEBUG
            AuthenticateViaAppOwnIdentity(app);
#else
AuthenticateViaAzureAD(app);
#endif    
        }
```

With this code, just try to change the build from debug to release and vice-versa. The running/excluded code will show changed in VS automatically as black and grayed out respectively