# How to stop evaluation of parameters in calls to debug functions when in Release build (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, release

I have some code which is littered with debug expressions similar to:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(System.BitConverter.ToString(data.Take(32).ToArray()));
```

What can I do to prevent the Release version evaluating `System.BitConverter.ToString(data.Take(32).ToArray())`?

I have added my own debug class that allows me to control calls to `WriteLine()` based on the level of reporting I want but both methods evaluate the Linq and string conversion even in Release mode (don't they)?

---ADDED LATER---

As I said above there are many of these lines in the code and I don't particularly want to `#if DEBUG` them all out.

What I want is to know how to avoid evaluating the Linq and the BitConverter, which I assume will be a performance hit, in Release mode.

Comment: Are you asking how to have certain code only execute in Debug? If so, that's [already been answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409598/need-net-code-to-execute-only-when-in-debug-configuration)

Comment: You could place a `#if DEBUG` directive around the according sections

Comment: It's only the internals of `Debug.WriteLine` that are not executed in release mode, the method is still called which is why the evaluation happens. You would either need to wrap these lines in `#if DEBUG...` (as mentioned by @LInsoDeTeh) or create your own method that decides what to output.

Comment: If you want to avoid the avaluation of the expression, a logging framework (or your own logging code) won't help. You only option is conditional compilation, which as @SpaceSteak says is covered elsewhere (so voting to close this as a duplicate).

Comment: The answer referred to does explain various options for conditional compilation but it doesn't explain whether `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` affects the evaluation of parameters being passed in the call. So it didn't answer my question (or at least the question I was trying to ask).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do not have to do anything! The evaluation of the parameters passed to a method that is removed because of the `ConditionalAttribute` is suppressed already.

See the section **[The Conditional attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664622.aspx)** in the C# Language Specification for authoritative documentation. Quote:

> [...]  the call (including evaluation of the parameters
>   of the call) is omitted.

To see that the method actually carries the [`ConditionalAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx), see [`Debug.WriteLine(string)` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z9k5ydz.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

The answers and comments prompted me to test my supposition that the conversion is evaluated in Release mode.

```
Console.WriteLine("Console:{0}", ++n);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Debug:{0}", ++n);
Console.WriteLine("Console:{0}", ++n);
```

In Release mode I get the output:

```
Console:1
Console:2
```

So the Debug line isn't being evaluated at-all in Release mode and I don't need to do any more than use the Debug output and/or add `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` to my own debug routines (which is already an attribute of the library Debug code).

`[Conditional("DEBUG")]` - although an attribute of the called function, prevents the function call which prevents the evaluation of parameters to it. It acts in a way very similar to `#if DEBUG`

Comment: Ah, while I was writing my answer, you found out yourself. You were first, so you may accept your own answer if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

`#if DEBUG` should solve it to you:

```
#if DEBUG
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(System.BitConverter.ToString(data.Take(32).ToArray()));
#endif
```

More examples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/4y6tbswk.aspx).